# Получить размеры элементов при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

Как известно, если пытаться получить размеры элементов экрана в `onCreate`, то они окажутся нулевыми. Каким образом можно получить реальные размеры?

Answer (score 2):

```
final View content = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {

    content.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

    //Now you can get the width and height from content
}
});
```